# Whatsapp's "WhatsApp Video" folder not visible from my PC

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, windows, media-files

I'm using Whatsapp on Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1) and several folders used by Whatsapp are not visible when accessed from a Windows 10 PC (connected through USB in MTP, file transfer mode).

From my PC "Whatsapp/Media" shows: [image: include 6 folders] while when accessed from the phone itself using my storage explorer I see 4 additional items:

- .Statuses
- Whatsapp Animated Gifs
- Whatsapp Audio
- Whatsapp Video

No .nomedia files inside those directories. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Apps -> tap the 3 vertical dots in upper right -> Show System -> scroll down to Media Storage and tap it -> tap Storage  -> tap Clear Data, and tap Clear Cache.

Then do a full power down reboot of your Nexus.  After it comes up wait a few minutes before connecting to your PC to allow the file system to be re-indexed the file system.

please try this :- Whastapp path has changed, it's now Android -> media -> com.whatsapp -> whatsapp

Comment: Life saver answer!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! It was a problem with "Google Photos" definition of media directories excluded from backup. All the missing folders were excluded from the backup definitions in Google Photos and when included (see image below) the directories became visible from the PC.

This seems to be a bug or some inconsistent situation, as removing them again from the backup definitions didn't cause the problem to return.

[image: Google Photos media directories]